# how to store picture in MySQL using android

Tags: android, mysql, encoding, base64

I trying to develop an android application that enables the user to add a picture from his gallery, it works fine and displays the picture in the image view.
the problem is I am trying to save this picture in MySQL database (not URL or path of it) I want to store as a blob.
I tried the below code to get the image from user's gallery and display it in the image view.
The attribute test2 is a string and it is what I save in the database

```
if (requestCode == GET_FROM_GALLERY && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK && data != null) {
    Uri selectedImageUri = data.getData();
    imagepath = getPath(selectedImageUri);
}
////// edit
Bitmap image = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imagepath);
FinalBytes = getBytes(image); // this will be save in DB
Bitmap getIt = getBitmap(FinalBytes);
imgV.setImageBitmap(getIt);
imgV.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
imgV.buildDrawingCache();
Bitmap testbit = imgV.getDrawingCache();
ByteArrayOutputStream testbyte = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
testbit.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, testbyte);
testbyte2 = testbyte.toByteArray();
base64Image = Base64.encodeToString(testbyte2, Base64.DEFAULT);
```

I used below code for retrieving the image

```
byte[] decodedString = Base64.decode(Recipes[position].getRimage(), Base64.DEFAULT);
Bitmap decodedByte = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(decodedString, 0, decodedString.length);
holder.image.setImageBitmap(decodedByte);
```

But I am getting this message when decoding it.

```
illegalargumentexception bad base 64
```

please help I spent 2 days on this error

Comment: maybe database field not have much space to store base64 string

Comment: Better store picture in Device and save the name in database so whenever you want to access that image you can retrieve name from database and use it

Comment: can you tell me resources of image then ill make code for you.

Comment: Display the hex for the first several bytes of `Recipes[position].getRimage()`.